# Regex find strings if preceeded by

Tags: regex

I have a text file in which is present the string

```
orderId=123456
```

The string can change but the format should always be orderId=six numbers.

I would like to extract the six numbers
I tryied with the following code

```
orderId=[0-9]{6}
```

but i do not know how to remove orderId=
could you please help?

---

UPDATE

Below an example of a string

```
&quot;display:none;&quot; name=&quot;LanguageSelectionForm&quot; action=&quot;http://pippo.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CabinSelectionView?packageType=onlyCruise&amp;amp;recommendedMaskCommission=false&amp;amp;catalogId=10001&amp;amp;catEntryId=360579&amp;amp;orderId=351026&amp;amp;storeId=10251&quot; method=&quot;post&quot; id=&quot;LanguageSelectionForm&quot;&gt;&#xd;
```

i'm using Jmeter and this response comes from http response

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: will "orderId=" be constant. Can you also paste the sample data

Comment: @user3299274 Did one of the answers help with the problem, or are you still wrestling with it? If an answer solves your problem, please consider "accepting it" by clicking the checkmark on the left, as this is how the reputation system works (accepting an anwer gives reputation to both the answerer and to you). Of course there is no obligation to do so. As you know, you can also upvotes any answer that is helpful. Thanks for listening to my 20-second SO rep tutorial. :)

Comment: Thank you your solution Saved My workday

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several options.

**Perl, PHP, Ruby 2**

Using `\K` with this short regex,

```
orderId=\K\d{6}
```

only the six digits will be matched.

**Flavors that support lookbehind**

```
(?<=orderId=)\d{6}
```

Again, only the six digits will be matched.

**Other flavors**

```
orderId=(\d{6})
```

Here, the whole string is captured, and the six digits are captured in Group 1, which can be examined in your language.

**How the regexes work**

> orderId=\K\d{6}

- Match the character string “orderId=” literally (case sensitive) `orderId=`
- Keep the text matched so far out of the overall regex match `\K`
- Match a single character that is a “digit” (0–9 in any Unicode script) `\d{6}`

  - Exactly 6 times `{6}`

> (?<=orderId=)\d{6}

- Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind) `(?<=orderId=)`

  - Match the character string “orderId=” literally (case sensitive) `orderId=`
- Match a single character that is a “digit” (0–9 in any Unicode script) `\d{6}`

  - Exactly 6 times `{6}`

> orderId=(\d{6})

- Match the character string “orderId=” literally (case sensitive) `orderId=`
- Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 `(\d{6})`

  - Match a single character that is a “digit” (0–9 in any Unicode script) `\d{6}`

    - Exactly 6 times `{6}`

Answer (score 1):

An expression like this will return, in group 1 the digits you require provided the input is in the form anyText=123456

```
[a-zA-Z]+=(\d{6})
```

If the string at the start doesn't change, then simply do this:

```
orderId=(\d{6})
```

Comment: the first part should always match orderId.

Comment: Your question says `The string can change`, is this not the case?

Comment: OrderID=sixnumber is fixed pattern The other part Can change

Comment: Then the 2nd regex I put in there will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex Extractor in Jmeter for below mentioned string:

> "display:none;" name="LanguageSelectionForm" action="http://pippo.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CabinSelectionView?packageType=onlyCruise&amp;recommendedMaskCommission=false&amp;catalogId=10001&amp;catEntryId=360579&amp;orderId=351026&amp;storeId=10251&quot; method="post" id="LanguageSelectionForm">

**Regular Expression** (to extract orderId): ".orderId=(.+?)&."

link for Reference:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jmeter/jmeter_regular_expressions.htm

Hope this will help.

Comment: Or just add parentheses   
**orderId=([0-9]{6})** and template as $1$  
  
Hope this will work